# program leaving blank line

Tags: python, file, line

This is a python program that i made to decrypt one time pads, but the program is leaving a blank line at the top of the decoded file, i do not know why it is leaving the line but i do know that it is related to how i use the top line, i use the top line to store the name of the file and then it is used to name a file for the decrypted text, the top line is then erased, but i do not know how to get rid of the blank line in the file.

```
import os

q = 1
while q == 1: 
    #opens the cipher text and it converts it to decimal
    cipher = raw_input("cipher text: ")
    cipher1 = open(cipher, "r")
    cipher2 = cipher1.read()
    cipher3 = [ord(c) for c in cipher2]

    #opens the key and coverts it to decimal
    key = raw_input("key: ")
    key1 = open(key, "r")
    key2 = key1.read()
    key3 = [ord(c) for c in key2]

    #subtracts the key from the cipher
    a = cipher3
    b = key3
    c = map(lambda x: (x[0]-x[1]) % 256, zip(a,b))

    #prints out the decrypted plain text
    decrypt = ''.join(map(chr,c))

    string1 = decrypt.index('\n')
    name = decrypt[0:string1]

    #makes a file with the decrypted output
    path1 = raw_input("out folder: ")
    path2 = path1 + "/" + name

    string3 = decrypt.index('\n')
    length = len(decrypt)
    decrypt = decrypt[string1:length]

    if os.path.exists(path2):
        f1 = file(path2, "a")
        f1 = open(path2, "a")
        f1.write(decrypt)
        f1.close()
    else:
        f1 = file(path2, "w")
        f1 = open(path2, "w")
        f1.write(decrypt)
        f1.close()
    print 50*"-"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
decrypt = decrypt[string1:length]
```

to

```
decrypt = decrypt[string1+1:length]
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that simple fix.

Comment: May I suggest to use more meaningful variable names. string1 might for example be named idxNameEnd.

Comment: That is a bad habit that i have been struggling with.

Comment: Well, if you think of the relative cost of the extra time to properly name variables vs the time wasted understanding your own code six months down the road,  you will lose the temptation to cut corners :-)

Answer (score 2):

You point your string1 to the end of line.

```
string1 = decrypt.index('\n')
```

but you need to slice from next character if this line:

```
decrypt = decrypt[string1:length]
```